# Use of undeclared identifier 'PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP'

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm trying to compile using gcc on macOS 10.14 with gcc in the Terminal.

I've included `#define _GNU_SOURCE` at the top of my C program, and `#include <pthread.h>`

But when I use the following: `gcc input.c -o output -lpthread` or `-pthread` I get the following error. I've also tried with `-std=c99`:

```
input.c:50:33: error: use of undeclared identifier
'PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP'
pthread_mutex_t request_mutex = PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;
```

---

Here's a summary of my code:

input.c:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
…
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t request_mutex = PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ...
}
```

**Edit**

I was able to get the code working by removing `_NP` at the end of `PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP`. Thanks for everyone's suggestions.

Comment: Under linux, this is defined in `pthread.h`, wrapped with `#ifdef __USE_GNU` [which is set when  you do `#define _GNU_SOURCE`. Other `.h` files treat the definition as optional (e.g. `#ifdef PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP`). So, you may need do a recursive `grep` in `/usr/include`, etc. to find the definition. It _may_ be optional/unimplemented in macOS. Or, you need something more than just `_GNU_SOURCE`

Comment: I just went to the `/usr` folder, and `include` doesn't seem to exist. According to the internet, macOS no longer contains it. I have Xcode command line tools installed. Where may I find what I need to include pthreads? If they're optional is it possible to get them?

Comment: I did some web search and it appears that `-pthread` is required for compiling with `clang` [and some pages suggest `-lpthread` when linking]. I'd defer to the two new answers you just got. The actual file could be in some really screwy place that isn't even under `/usr`. With the right compiler/preprocessor trace options, they could tell you where the file is (or you could run `clang` under `strace`). But, I think the answers below give you your best shot (i.e.) initialize it early, dynamically. It's portable and [probably] not worth diddling more with macOS on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_GNU_SOURCE` will not do anything to reveal library extensions on Mac OS, because Mac OS isn't from the GNU project and doesn't use the GNU C library.

On Mac OS, the "reveal extensions" feature selection macro is `_DARWIN_C_SOURCE`.

However, this will not necessarily reveal a `PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP`; I don't think it exists. Of course, the recursive mutex type `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` exists; only there is no initializer to set one up statically. The code will have to be ported to explicitly call `pthread_mutex_init` to initialize its recursive mutexes.

Another idea is to just write code that doesn't require recursive mutexes. Recursive mutexes are for "scatter brained" concurrent programming. "Well, I don't know whether I already have this lock or not, so I will grab it just in case." The sane alternative is to design the program so that you know!

Recursive mutexes are essentially a band-aid solution for certain situations that arise when when legacy single-threaded code is being converted to multithreading. Recursive mutexes are out of place in a completely new design.

If you avoid recursive mutexes, you can use the standard `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`.

Answer (score 3):

`PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP` is a non-standard extension, and evidently MacOS doesn't support it.

You should instead initialise your mutex at the beginning of `main()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t request_mutex;

int init_recursive_mutex(pthread_mutex_t *mutex)
{
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
    int r;

    r = pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    if (r != 0)
        return r;

    r = pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);

    if (r == 0)
        r = pthread_mutex_init(mutex, &attr);

    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);

    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int r;

    r = init_recursive_mutex(&request_mutex);
    if (r != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialise request_mutex: %s\n", strerror(r));
        return 1;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: The `_np` or `_NP` suffixes to thread functions etc is intended to be used to indicate 'non-portable' extensions compared with the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) specification — but I confess I couldn't find a statement to that effect in the standard (which isn't a big surprise).  I probably read about it in a book on pthreads — maybe the one by [Butenhof](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0201633922/).

Answer (score 1):

`PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is available on OSX, but only starting from 10.7, so if you have to support earlier versions, you have to either initialize mutex directly before use (like @caf suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53075997/814297)) or initialize it lazily using `pthread_once`:

```
#if ((__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED && __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 1070) || (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 50000)) || defined(__DRIVERKIT_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED)

static pthread_mutex_t s_mutex = PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int lock() {
  return pthread_mutex_lock(&s_mutex);
}

int unlock() {
  return pthread_mutex_unlock(&s_mutex);
}

#else

static pthread_mutex_t s_mutex;
static pthread_once_t s_mutex_init = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

static void init_mutex() {
  init_recursive_mutex(&s_mutex);
} 

int lock() {
  pthread_once(&s_mutex_init, init_mutex);
  return pthread_mutex_lock(&s_mutex);
} 

int unlock() {
  return pthread_mutex_unlock(&s_mutex);
}

#endif
```